# What's the problem with db ,can't read and go to other page

Tags: php

I can't go to the page home whats is the problem i cant read from database

```
<?php 

include_once('user.php');

if(isset($POST['submit'])){

    $username=$_POST['user'];
    $password=$_POST['pass'];

    $object = new Users();
    $object->Login($username , $password);
}

include_once ('connection.php');
 class Users{

     private $db;

     public function __constuct(){
         $this->db = new Connection();
         $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();

     }

     public function Login($username , $password){
         if(!empty($name) && !empty($pass)){
             $st = $this->db->prepare("select * from users  where username =? and password =? ");
             $st->bindParam(1, $username);
             $st->bindParam(2, $password);
             $st->execute();

             if($st->rowCount() ==1){
                header("location:home.php");

             }else{
                 echo"wrong";
             }


     }else{
         echo"enter username & password";
     }

     }  
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

More questions than answers...
what are these files? Are they in the same directory? Does they contain any html? Or, possibly your functions?

```
include_once('user.php');       
include_once ('connection.php');
```

You never define this variable.

```
private $db;
```

Are you calling these functions, or creating them?

```
public function __constuct(){...
public function Login($username , $password){...
```

Make sure you capitalize "Location" (it's also good practice to exit here) and double check to make sure that your "home.php" page is in the same directory as the script.

```
exit(header("Location:home.php"));
```

Those were the things that had me scratching my head. Your problem might be as simple as you didn't capitalize "Location", but I suspect it's more of a combination of things.